# How to format date in android output as : 11/12/2013 4:21 PM

Tags: android, date, format, timestamp

I have a timestamp in String which returns me below value in Android application

```
1398876631
```

How can i format it into below value

```
11/12/2013 4:21 PM
```

Comment: Did you searched over the SO?

Comment: Yes, I searched but i couldn't find an answer where the input is string and output is the format i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert your timestamp to a Date

```
Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong(timestamp) * 1000);
```

Then with SimpleDateFormat you can format your date as you want

```
String result = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm").format(d);
```

Comment: Integer overflow: use longs for millisecond timestamps, e.g. `1000L` instead of `1000`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below function. Here you have to pass miliseconds and date format (like dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss aa)

```
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
    {
        // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

        // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date. 
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
         return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

Example

```
Log.i("====== Date "," :: "+getDate(1398876631,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm aa"))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your Problem answer**

```
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a");
 String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
 Log.d("date",date.toString());// Output 01/09/2014 10:59 AM
```

Where as you can have DateFormat patterns such as:

```
"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z" ---- 2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz" ----------- 12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"------- Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700
 "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"------- 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
 "yyMMddHHmmssZ"-------------------- 010704120856-0700
 "K:mm a, z" ----------------------- 0:08 PM, PDT
 "h:mm a" -------------------------- 12:08 PM
 "EEE, MMM d, ''yy" ---------------- Wed, Jul 4, '01
```

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info.